# How can I delete my comment or reply on a SharePoint modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, comments

I have added a new SharePoint modern page, and on the tenant level I have enabled commenting on modern pages, as follows:

[image]

But now if I add a comment to a modern page or if I add a reply to an existing comment, I am unable to delete these messages or replies, as it seems there is not any delete link available:

[image]

Can anyone advice me if there is a way to enable deleting comments and replies from modern pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi SharePoint TestDev,

I think delete option is already exist on every comment column by clicking (...) but i am not sure the audience level whether all can delete the comments or only site owners can delete it

[image]

Comment: now i did not noticed the delete link, thanks for the reply. but now seems delete is working more than what i expected. as seems anyone with contribute permission on the pages can delete others comments? not sure if there is a way to control this? so to only allow users to delete their own reply/comments (comment and replies created by them)?

Comment: i think your rely has fixed my main problem ..i created another question regarding if we can prevent users from deleting others comments and replies @ https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252129/on-sharepoint-modern-pages-can-we-only-allow-users-to-delete-their-own-comments